# Udev triggers are not firing on insert of CF card into USB card reader (anymore)

Tags: linux, debian, usb, udev

I've got a `udev` rule that triggers a shell script that copies photos off my CF card when I insert the card into my USB card reader.  This worked fine for a while.  But after a recent upgrade it has stopped working.

The problem (AFAICT) is that inserting the CF card into the USB reader is no longer triggering any `udev` events, so my script never runs.  (Even the entries in `/dev/disk/by-label/` don't show up on insert, and `dmesg` shows nothing about the insert.)

I can cause the `udev` events to trigger if I run `fdisk -l /dev/sdf` (or `sdh` or whatever device it is that seems to be where the CF card will appear).  I've verified the `udev` events with `udevadm monitor`, and by running `udevd --debug`.  After I manually trigger the system, the script works fine from this point.

I'm running Debian 6.0 (Squeeze), and I'm pretty confident it was the upgrade from Lenny a couple months back that changed the behavior, but I'm not sure if it was some subtle change in `udev` (perhaps I'm listening for the wrong events?) or some change in the kernel or USB stack?  Anyway, anyone have suggestions for how to fix this?  Or suggestions for getting more debugging info out of the usb-storage module?

This is the udev rule I'm using:

```
KERNEL=="sd??", SUBSYSTEM=="block", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/hot-add"
```

#### Update #1: Trigger on blockdev and partition changes

I added a rule to trigger on just the block device instead of on a partition (in case that might show up), but it doesn't trigger when I insert the CF card either:

```
KERNEL=="sd?", SUBSYSTEM=="block", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/hot-add-disk"
```

Oddly, if I run `fdisk -l /dev/sdf` to trigger recognition of the CF card, I get a "changed" event for `/dev/sdf` (even though I never got an "add" event).

#### Update #2: `add` uevent triggers

There is an open, incomplete [Debian bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=648810) that covers some similar ground (skip to [Update#25](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=648810#25) for the relevant bits).  That has some handy tips.

For my setup, if I do (as root) `echo add > /sys/block/sdf/uevent` with the CF card inserted but otherwise unrecognized, that will trigger all the `udev` events properly and all my scripts run correctly.

Running `udevadm info --query=all --name=sdf` before and after inserting the CF card shows no difference.  If I inject the 'add' event and re-run the `udevadm` command I get a bit more output (there is some information about disk partitions).

#### Update #3: USB key vs. CF card in USB reader

Inserting a vanilla USB key triggers all the `udev` events immediately and works just fine.  Inserting a CF card into the USB card reader does not.  For the card reader, it seems that the USB device "exists" even when no CF card is inserted (so a `/sys/block/sdf` entry exists), but with the USB key, the `/sys/block/sdj` only exists while the USB key is plugged in.

#### Update #4: Maybe fixed in 2.6.38

This [Ubuntu bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/713478) has an update (the last one) that claims the bug was no longer present in a 2.6.38 kernel.

#### Update #5: Not fixed (in 3.2.0)

I've upgraded the kernel a couple times, and even changed the motherboard I'm using, and I still see the same problem.  I'm currently at a 3.2.0.0 kernel.  And `udev` version 164.

Comment: Running `lspci` apparently triggers something because messages appear in `dmesg`: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182399/sd-card-insert-remove-behaviors-not-detected-until-running-lspci-command/1182400#1182400

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr:** See solution at Update 2 below.

This is not really an answer sadly, or at least not good news: I'm getting the feeling that this can never work anyway — I just find that a little hard to believe since I surely think this has worked in the past!

This is what usually works, and why: Most laptop SD card readers. You'll find that you plug in an SD card, `udev` sees it, Linux will scan it for partitions and automounting will just work. Why does this work? Look at `lsusb` before and after inserting the card. You'll note that with no SD card plugged in, the USB device doesn't exist. So when you insert an SD card, there's a full-blown USB hotplug event.

The card reader in my monitor doesn't seem to work like this, it's always there. And I can't get it to generate any event when I insert an SD card. I started with looking at syslogs, then on to `udevadm monitor`, then `usbmon` for raw USB event logging. No luck, there doesn't seem to be any insert/eject notification/event at all, from either the card reader in my monitor or the cheap DealExtreme one in my PC.

The moment I try to access the raw device, the kernel wakes up and the partition appears. Similarly, call `udevadm trigger` and it'll note the device. Take out the card and nothing happens until I try to access the device again and the kernel realises it's gone.

What I wonder myself now is, how could this ever have worked (that is, if I'm not making up this memory)? Maybe some daemon used to be polling the raw device every few seconds and stopped doing this? It's hard to find any documentation on this, really.

#### Update #1

Above is all with a Debian stock kernel. I've just done some experiments with an Ubuntu kernel, where SD card hotplugging appears to work. And not surprisingly, in `usbmon` I see polls every two seconds. Which does also explain why the cards aren't detected immediately but with a slight delay.

The polling seems to be done by the kernel, since it happens even in single-user mode with no userland process doing anything other than being stuck in a `select()` loop. I haven't been able to figure out where in the kernel this is done, I'll update this post if I find out.

#### Update #2

The important difference seems to be `/sys/block/sd?/events_poll_msecs`. On my Debian box it's -1, on the Ubuntu box it's 2000. This `udev` rule seems to do it:

```
# enable in-kernel media-presence polling
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="module", KERNEL=="block", ATTR{parameters/events_dfl_poll_msecs}=="0", ATTR{parameters/events_dfl_poll_msecs}="2000"
ACTION=="add", ATTR{removable}=="1", ATTR{events_poll_msecs}=="-1", ATTR{events_poll_msecs}="2000"
```